# Why do we feel hot because of sunlight?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

sunlight , light generally , is an electromagnetic wave which turns into heat when it contacts a matter (solid,liquid,etc..) is that right ?

Comment: Does [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer#Radiation) clarify things? If not, what about it is unclear?

Comment: its mentionned that energy of electromagnetic waves is transported by photons , lets just focus on light , i think they aborded the wave-particule dualty if im not wrong but the thing is that light can either behave as particule or a wave and not both im still confused about this too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Light like sunlight is an electromagnetic wave with components with different frequencies. These components follow a particular distribution of intensities. One portion of the energy of this light resides in what is called [infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared#Heat) radiation and most materials absorb in that range (link provides some more extra information regarding this radiation and heat). This absorption predominantly causes the heating of matter that you mention.

Comment: There's nothing special about infrared light.  A lot of materials absorb visible radiation too (e.g., pretty much anything that is not white as snow) and a substantial fraction of solar energy is in the visible part of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

The light you see that comes from the sun is all radiation on the visible light spectrum, there is also a whole lot of light that comes from the sun that isn't visible to the human eye. Most of this radiation is absorbed by your skin and the radiation excited the electrons in your skin, giving them more energy, which feels warm. Some light like ultraviolet radiation which is a higher frequency than your eyes can pick up are actually so intense that they can give you a sunburn.

If you are standing too close to a nuclear detonation, you skin rapidly absorbs an extremely large amount of gamma radiation, which penetrates easily through the skin and basically excites your entire body's electrons so much, so fast, that you completely vaporize almost instantly.

Radiation is fun!

Comment: "excited the electrons in your skin, giving them more energy, which feels warm." I think you missed a step where the electrons relax to their ground states by emitting some kinetic energy to nearby atoms. In a crystal this would be called a phonon emisison; I'm not sure what it is called in a big water bag.

Comment: Also, some radiation can directly stimulate kinetic motion in molecules without needing an electron excitation as an itermediate step. Think about how a CO2 laser works.